# Capture https web page that user is viewing in his browser

Tags: cookies, https, webkit, capture

I am developing a Desktop application that allows the user to capture the contents of a web page loaded in web-browser. I take the URL from the browser, then load the contents into my WebView and then create image out of it. It works fine with http URLs. The problem comes when I have to capture https URL contents.

1. Suppose I have a login page with https URL displayed in the browser, I get this URL from the browser and try to load it in my web view. I get the following error:

   > The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “<url>” which could put your confidential information at risk.
2. If user has logged in to a web page and viewing some contents in Safari browser. Now, if he wants to capture the entire web page, he comes back to my app. But, my app is not able to capture these contents. The reason is that, once user logs into a site, cookies are written into his system and this is browser specific. Hence, my web view is not able to directly enter into the page that user is viewing in the browser.

Even though technically it sounds right, user will not accept this behavior in my app.

How do I solve this? Is there any alternative method to capture the entire web page that user is viewing in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

You could investigate making your application a browser plugin for those browsers on your target platform.

Comment: I am not a web-developer. So, can we write browser plugin using cocoa/objective-c?